# Reading integers from file

Tags: java

There is a problem, which says that try to read integers from the file which has some integers and text,and they are separated from each other by space, like the file xxx.txt: I like a apple which is 45 pounds,and 6 yuan 45 lk 56 ds ,like this,now read all the integers from the file,and add them, the example above should be resulted as 45+6+45+56=152, it is written in java code,please give me the code in java .

Comment: Did you try to solve your problem?

Comment: please dont tell us to please do your homework for you :)

Comment: No code, only hint, read the line, use StringTokenizer to get the tokens, try to convert them into integer with Integer.parseInt, the text part will not parse and throw NumberFormatException, handle that and move on to the next token. It there is no NFE, its an integer and add it to whatever variable you are using. And yes, you should first attempt to solve this, homework or not, before asking for help.

Comment: @Ironluca what is this solution? did you really understand meaning of exception?

Comment: @AliAmiri, certainly, first let 152 appear on System.out, then we shall go to the part as to how Exceptions are to be used and handled and java.utilScanner but first the number 152 :)

Comment: @Ironluca certainly not, this problem could be solved in million ways, why would somebody choose worst solution?!

Comment: @AliAmiri, this is not the right place to go into philosophy of design and what is the best solution and is the worst solution (if such a concept ever exists) but it shall be sufficient to say that the worst solution (in your terms) still gets the job done. In addition, while the below answer of Mihai is good, do you think introducing Regex to a person who is struggling with basis is a good idea. Is it not better to show something that works and progressively go to the higher levels of knowledge. But then since you keep the view of a 'best' & 'worst' solution, perhaps your views are different.

Comment: @Ironluca first of all, no I would give OP an answer with regex if I wanted to answer. And beside that, it is not a place to show people how to code completely wrong! With a code like, not only OP will never learn a thing, but his progress through learning would be much harder(when it comes to learn about handling exception he has the wrong Idea of handling exception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static int getSum(String line) {
    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+"); //regex to extract numbers from string
    final Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
    int sum = 0;
    while (m.find()) {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(m.group());
    }
    return sum;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("xxx.txt"));

    System.out.println("--------");
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        final String line = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
        System.out.println("Sum is: " + getSum(line)); //for each line get the sum
        System.out.println("--------");
    }
    scanner.close();
}
```

Comment: Great answer, but please dont gave complete homework answers!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the FileReader Class: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html

The FileReader Class provides anything you need to read the text from a File.

Another proposal is to look at the Scanner Class:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Furthermore, I recommend you to look at the String Class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

The String Class provides anything you need to convert the text of your file into integers, to split the text from the integers to compute a result and much more.

Happy learning!